# How to show f(x) together with slopes toward f(x-d) and f(x+d) with intermediate values unknown?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

Suppose x is one of the elements of my elements on the x-axis. Now assuming that for a constant d, let `right-slope = [f(x+d)-f(x)]/d` and `left-slope = [f(x)-f(x-d)]/d`, for every `x`, which we know.

What I want is to plot a marker (a diamond or a plus as in the figure) at `B = (x,f(x))`, and the segment just to the left (`AB`) and right (`BC`) of B should represent the left-slope and right-slope respectively, i.e., the slope of `AB` should be left-slope and slope of BC should be the right slope.

I think what this essentially boils down to is this: You know `f(x)` for every `x` in your x-array. You also know `f(x-d)` and `f(x+d)` for all these `x`, given a small constant `d`. Now you want to plot such that only `[x-d,f(x-d)]`, `[x,f(x)], [x+d,f(x+d)]` are connected by a line for every `x`.

How exactly can I plot a graph this way for all such elements like `x` in the x-array, in python?

Comment: @JohanC yes sir I just marked it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach creates 4 entries in `fn` for every entry in `f`. The first corresponds to the left values, the second to the f-values themselves, the third to the right values and the fourth is just `np.nan`. Note that when `nan` is encountered in a plot command, a gap is created. There are 4 corresponding x-values, one at x-d, one at x,  one at x+d and one that isn't important as is won't be drawn.

The following code first creates some test data from a sine function (`sin(x^2)`). In reality these values will come from a more complicated calculation.

If you only have the slopes, you can calculate `f_right = f + right_slope*d`. And similar for `f_left = f - left_slope*d`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

d = .04
x = np.linspace(0, 4, 20)
f = np.sin(x ** 2)
f_left = np.sin((x - d) ** 2)
f_right = np.sin((x + d) ** 2)

xn = np.repeat(x, 4)
xn[::4] -= d
xn[2::4] += d

fn = np.column_stack([f_left, f, f_right, np.full_like(f, np.nan)]).ravel()

plt.plot(x, f, marker='D', ls='', color='crimson')
plt.plot(xn, fn, color='navy')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thanks a ton, this is exactly what I wanted! :)